# Resource object not found

Tags: .net, object, resources

I have backed up a client's .Net website and trying to run it on my localhost but I keep getting this error which I am not sure what to do about.

**The resource object with key 'HomeBody' was not found.**

I am running Windows 7 and IIS7 so I am not sure if there is something in my configuration I need to set for it to work.

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you missed the resource file (RESX) that accompanies some control, page or masterpage, which requires that a resource file contains a "HomeBody" string resource (some localization thing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied all resource files?

These normally live in `App_LocalResources` or `App_GlobalResources`.

Comment: Thanks guys, will check into this now. I thought I had copied all the files but maybe something went wrong in the transfer